# Imprimir coluna criada em Select em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela de projetos e dentro deste projetos tenho vários alunos.
Fiz um `select` nas duas tabelas para poder contar quantos alunos há em cada projeto, portanto fiz o select assim :

```
Select inscricao.id, 
       inscricao.titulo, 
       inscricao.orientador, 
       inscricao.email_professor, 
       inscricao.escola, 
       inscricao.habilitacao, 
       inscricao.serie, 
       (select count(alunos.id_inscricao) as 'qtde_alunos' from alunos where alunos.id_inscricao=inscricao.id) 
from inscricao order by inscricao.titulo
```

Porém não entendi como faço para imprimir a coluna que foi criada para contar os registro em PHP.

Peguei a coluna assim:

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{   
        id = $registro['id'];
        $titulo = utf8_decode($registro['titulo']);
        $escola = utf8_decode($registro['escola']);
        $habilitacao = utf8_decode($registro['habilitacao']);
        $serie = $registro['serie'];
        $qtde_alunos =$registro['qtde_alunos'];
 }
```

Mas ele não imprime o valor da variavel `$qtde_alunos`.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa adicionar o `alias` no resultado do sub-select ao invés de dentro dele:

```
 select inscricao.id,
       inscricao.titulo,
       inscricao.orientador,
       inscricao.email_professor,
       inscricao.escola,
       inscricao.habilitacao,
       inscricao.serie,
       (select count(alunos.id_inscricao) -- não aqui
          from alunos
         where alunos.id_inscricao = inscricao.id) as 'qtde_alunos' -- aqui
  from inscricao
 order by inscricao.titulo
```

Utilize a função var_dump para visualizar as variáveis com mais detalhes, isso vai facilitar bastante a sua vida:

```
while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
     var_dump($resultado);
}
```